# How do I remove duplicates from excel range? c#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I've converted  cells in my excel range from strings to form a string list and have separated each item after the comma in the original list. I am starting to think I have not actually separated each item, and they are still one whole, trying to figure out how to do this properly so that each item( ie. the_red_bucket_01)is it's own string.

example of original string in a cell 1 and 2:

Cell1 :

```
the_red_bucket_01, the_blue_duck_01,_the green_banana_02, the orange_bear_01
```

Cell2 :

```
the_purple_chair_01, the_blue_coyote_01,_the green_banana_02, the orange_bear_01
```

The new list looks like this, though I'm not sure they are separate items:

```
the_red_bucket_01
the_blue_duck_01
the green_banana_02
the orange_bear_01
the_red_chair_01
the_blue_coyote_01
the green_banana_02
the orange_bear_01
```

Now I want to remove duplicates so that the console only shows 1 of each item, no matter how many there are of them, I can't seem to get my foreah/if statements to work. It is printing out multiple copies of the items, I'm assuming because it is iterating for each item in the list, so it is returning the data that many items.

```
 foreach (Excel.Range item in xlRng)
                    {
                        string itemString = (string)item.Text;


                        List<String> fn = new List<String>(itemString.Split(','));


                        List<string> newList = new List<string>();

                        foreach (string s in fn)
                        if (!newList.Contains(s))
                        {
                            newList.Add(s);
                        }
                        foreach (string combo in newList)
                        {
                            Console.Write(combo);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the distinct items while you are reading, then just use the `Distinct` operator like `fn.Distinct()`

For processing the whole data, I can suggest two methods:

1. Read in the whole data then use LINQ's `Distinct` operator
2. Or use a `Set` data structure and store each element in that while reading the excel

I suggest that you take a look at the LINQ documentation if you are processing data. It has really great extensions. For even more methods, you can check out the `MoreLINQ` package.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to trim the strings, because they have leading white spaces, so "string1" is different from " string1".

```
foreach (string s in fn)
if (!newList.Contains(s.Trim()))
{
     newList.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much simpler with Linq by using [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
foreach (Excel.Range item in xlRng)
{
    string itemString = (string)item.Text;

    List<String> fn = new List<String>(itemString.Split(','));
    foreach (string combo in fn.Distinct())
    {
         Console.Write(combo);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, you may also need to `Trim` any whitespace, in which case you would do:

```
fn.Select(x => x.Trim()).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you need to contain keys/values, its better to use Dictionary type. Try changing code with `List<T>` to `Dictionary<T>`. i.e.
From:

```
List<string> newList = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in fn)
if (!newList.Containss))
{
     newList.Add(s);
}
```

to

```
Dictionary<string, string> newList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string s in fn)
if (!newList.ContainsKey(s))
{
     newList.Add(s, s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code would probably work as you expect if you moved newList out of the loop - you create a new variable named newList each loop so it's not going to find duplicates from earlier loops.

You can do all of this this more concisely with Linq:

```
//set up some similar data
string list1 = "a,b,c,d,a,f";
string list2 = "a,b,c,d,a,f";
List<string> lists = new List<string> {list1,list2};

// find unique items
var result = lists.SelectMany(i=>i.Split(',')).Distinct().ToList();
```

SelectMany() "flattens" the list of lists into a list.

Distinct() removes duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
var uniqueItems = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (Excel.Range cell in xlRng)
{
    var cellText = (string)cell.Text;

    foreach (var item in cellText.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()))
    {
        uniqueItems.Add(item);
    }
}

foreach (var item in uniqueItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```